# How do you list what smart packages have been added to a Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In [meteor](http://meteor.com), how do you, from the root directory of a meteor app, figure out which smart packages have been added. `meteor list` shows all available packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the --using parameter.  Thus:

```
meteor list --using
```

To see which parameters are available for a meteor command, pass the --help parameter.  Thus:

```
meteor list --help
```

... which returns:

```
Usage: meteor list [--using]

Without arguments, lists all available Meteor packages. 
To add one of these packages to your project, see 'meteor add'.

With --using, list the packages that you have added to your project.
```